# itext 5.5 Portrait orientation not working from new page

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I run the following code for an `HTML` file with Tables.
I am able to convert `HTML` to `PDF` for first page with margins all sides.
But as I do `document.newPage();` and apply `document.setPageSize();` its not working.  Margins are not present.
`PDF` is borderless, without any margins.
Pls guide.

Code:

```
public class Potrait_ParseHtmlObjects {

public static final String HTML = "C:/h.html";
public static final String DEST = "C:/test33.pdf";

public void createPdf(String file)  {

    // Parse HTML into Element list

    try{ 
    XMLWorkerHelper helper = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
    // CSS
    CSSResolver cssResolver = helper.getDefaultCssResolver(true);

    CssFile cssFile = helper.getCSS(new FileInputStream("D:\\Itext_Test\\Test\\src\\test.css"));
    cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

    // HTML
    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
    htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
    htmlContext.autoBookmark(false);

    //mycode starts
    FontFactory.registerDirectories();
    //mycode ends


    // Pipelines
    ElementList elements = new ElementList();
    ElementHandlerPipeline end = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, null);
    HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, end);
    CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

    // XML Worker
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);


    //mycode starts        

    p.parse(new FileInputStream(HTML),Charset.forName("UTF-8"));//changed for Charset Encoding

    // step 1


    Document document = new Document();

    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    writer.setInitialLeading(12.5f);

    // step 3
    document.open();

    // step 4

    Rectangle left =  new Rectangle(33,33,550,770); 

    document.setPageSize(left);
    System.out.println("1"+document.getPageSize());



    ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
    column.setSimpleColumn(left);

    int runDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR;

    column.setRunDirection(runDirection);

    int status = ColumnText.START_COLUMN;
    for (Element e : elements) {

        if (e instanceof PdfPTable) {

            PdfPTable table = (PdfPTable) e;
            for (PdfPRow row : table.getRows()) {
                for (PdfPCell cell : row.getCells()) {
                    if(cell!=null)
                    cell.setRunDirection(runDirection);
                }
            }
        }


        if (ColumnText.isAllowedElement(e)) {
            column.addElement(e);
            status = column.go();

            while (ColumnText.hasMoreText(status)) {
                Rectangle left1 = new Rectangle(50,50,500,700); 
                    document.newPage();
                    document.setPageSize(left1);
                    column.setSimpleColumn(left1);
                status = column.go();
            }

        }
    }



    // step 5
    document.close();
}catch(Exception ex)
{ex.printStackTrace();}
}

/**
 * Main method
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new Potrait_ParseHtmlObjects().createPdf(DEST);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize all page parameters when you do `document.newPage()`, hence changing the page size or margins doesn't make sense *after* triggering `document.newPage()`. If you want a different page size (or orientation, or margins), you need to set the values for the page size, orientation and margins *before* invoking `document.newPage()` (and *before* `document.open()` if you want to change the first page).

For instance: in your case, you should create your document like this:

```
Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(33,33,550,770));
```

And you should change the page size like this:

```
document.setPageSize(left1);
document.newPage();
column.setSimpleColumn(left1);
```

You don't have any margins because you use the same `Rectangle` for the page size as for the column. You are creating a PDF of which the coordinate of the lower-left corner is not equal to `(0, 0)`. This isn't illegale, but it's unusual. My guess is that you want to do something like this:

```
document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(0, 0, 550, 750););
document.newPage();
column.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(50,50,500,700));
```

This will result in a page size of 7.64 by 10.42 inch (550 by 750 pt) and you'll have a margin of 0
69 inches on every side (50 pt).

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruno! :-) I used the second snippet for a 50pt border.